# Can we use CrudRepository and ReactiveCrudRepository simaultaneously in the application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using couchbase in my springboot application and using both ReactiveCrudRepository and CrudRepository separately. But while using CrudRepository method it is throwing me the following error
 "reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly cannot be cast to my POJO

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in the same project but they have to be different classes and implement different interfaces.

Synchronous Repository:

```
public interface UserEntityRepository extends 
    CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<UserEntity, String> {
}
```

Async Repository:

```
public interface ReactiveUserEventRepository extends 
    ReactiveCouchbaseSortingRepository<UserEventEntity, String> {

 }
```

There is a big tutorial talking about it here: https://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/profile-store/java.html#storing-user-events

Comment: yes, I am creating the different interface but when I am using the findById method from reactive as well non-reactive. Then the non-reactive one is throwing me an error that Mono cannot be cast to POJO.

Comment: Please find the repo link where i have implemented both sync and async way
https://github.com/bhawna94/Spring-Boot-Reactive/tree/feature/CRUD-reactive